# Combine two columns data with first char of second column into one column leaving null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below:

```
------------------
| Scode  | Ucode  |
-------------------
| qwei   | we2    |
| iu76   | oi     |
| ikhj   | null   |
| null   | ikj    |
-------------------
```

I want output like below

```
----------------------------
| Scode | ucode | Finalcode |
-----------------------------
| qwei  | we2   | qweiw     |
| iu76  | oi    | iu76o     |
-----------------------------
```

I want to fetch the first column value and the first char of the second column. In case the first column is null or the second column is null then it will not come in the table.

At present, I just take the first column and second column first char by using the below code

```
Select Scode+left(Ucode,1) as finalcode into ##test from table
```

I want to ignore the `null` value of `Scode` and `Ucode` and fetch the first column and only the first char of the second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (Scode varchar(50),Ucode varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('qwei','we2')

select *,scode + substring(ucode,1,1) from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you're only missing a couple of `null` checks:

```
SELECT scode + LEFT(ucode, 1) AS finalcode
INTO   ##test
FROM   mytable
WHERE  scode IS NOT NULL AND ucode IS NOT NULL -- Here
```